# How to remove Margins and spaces in a row

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, row

I'm learning Flutter, I'm  trying to develop through examples. Recently, I was trying to control separate widgets through the main widget.
But I was not able to bring the separate widgets side by side, without margin.
At this point, I also tried crossalignement and mainaxis alignements but without success.

Here is main.dart:

```
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: const [
            Flexible(child: MyButton()), //Here is call for widget from MyButton
            Flexible(child: MyButton()),
            Flexible(child: MyButton()),
            Flexible(child: MyButton()),
            Flexible(child: MyButton()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is widget design to call button.dart

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: const Color.fromARGB(225, 5, 27, 39),
            border: Border.all(
              color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 34, 156, 236),
              width: 4,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the photo of the Application and description of the trouble

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to have scaffold on your MyButton widget.

```dart
class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 200,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: const Color.fromARGB(225, 5, 27, 39),
        border: Border.all(
          color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 34, 156, 236),
          width: 4,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And use `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,` to have minimum space for row

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: const [
            Flexible(child: MyButton()), //Here is call for widget from MyButton
            Flexible(child: MyButton()),
            Flexible(child: MyButton()),
            Flexible(child: MyButton()),
            Flexible(child: MyButton()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your "Mybutton" widget doesn't need to have a scaffold:

```
class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 200,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: const Color.fromARGB(225, 5, 27, 39),
        border: Border.all(
          color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 34, 156, 236),
          width: 4,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Scaffold widget is a widget for the scaffold of your pages as it's named, where you need to have an appbar, a bottom sheet, a drawer or ...

Answer (score 0):

you can make myButton widget type, dont have to use the Scaffold in button.

```
Widget MyButton(){
  return Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 200,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: const Color.fromARGB(225, 5, 27, 39),
        border: Border.all(
          color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 34, 156, 236),
          width: 4,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
      ),
    );
}
```

then you can call the rest:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: const [
            Flexible(child: MyButton()), //Here is call for widget from MyButton
            Flexible(child: MyButton()),
            Flexible(child: MyButton()),
            Flexible(child: MyButton()),
            Flexible(child: MyButton()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```